# sending XML containing a file with curl and PHP 7

Tags: php, xml, curl

The XML has a label where I indicate the path of the file, they tell me that I must use DIME to make the shipment.

```
$URL = "http://localhost:8080/data/info/USD_R11_WebService?wsdl";
$ch = curl_init();
 $xml='
 '.$sid.'rep_doc:1002iss:519605Adjunto_Evidencia/home/sftpserver/jperoza/public_html/data/uploads/28.png';
 $headers = array();
 array_push($headers, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;application/xml; charset=US-ASCII");
 array_push($headers, "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='chg'");
 array_push($headers, "SOAPAction: '';");
 if($xml != null) {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml");
     array_push($headers, "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml));
 }
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



 if (curl_errno($ch)) 


{
     // moving to display page to display curl errors
       echo curl_errno($ch) ;
       echo curl_error($ch);
 } 
 else 
 {
     //getting response from server
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
      print_r($response);
      curl_close($ch);
 }
```

After executing it I get the message policy limit exceeded (there is no attachment), the integration is with CA service desk

stackoverflow remove xml tags, but if you have them

Comment: your $xml variable does not contain valid XML-formatted data, not even close. `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;application/xml; charset=US-ASCII` is neither valid for saying `the request body contains XML`, nor is it valid for saying `the request body contains multipart/form-data`  (and because your $xml variable is invalid, it does in fact contain neither of those)

Comment: stackoverflow remove xml tags, but if you have them

Comment: if you add 4 spaces to each newline for the XML, stackoverflow will not remove the tags.